# Return when subscribing. ... Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I am subscribing a response from an Angular service:

```
  books: BookModel[] = [];

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.books = this.getBooks();

  }

  getBooks(): BookModel[] {

    return this.bookService.getByCategoryId(1).subscribe((payload: Payload<GetBooksResponse>) => {

      return payload.result.map((response: GetBooksResponse) => { 

        return {
          id: response.id, 
          title: response.title
        };

      });

    });

  }
```

When I add `return` to `this.bookService`, e.g., `return this.bookService` I get the error:

```
Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'BookModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

How can I use return to make this work?

**Update: BookModel:**

```
export interface BookModel {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do after returning from subscribe? There is no use of that unless you want to unsubscribe later

Comment: I want to display the books on a list using ngFor

Comment: this.books will be the variable to which ngFor will be applied

Comment: At the moment I am using getBooks only in this component but I might, in a near future, use it on another component. That is why I am trying to return and not just use this.books = ... inside subscribe.

Comment: There is no need to return from a subscription and I don't see `this.books` assignment

Comment: I have the assignment on ngOnInit. The reason why I am doing it there and not inside getBooks is because other components might use getBooks later on.

Comment: No, what you have to understand is, when you do : `return this.bookService.getByCategoryId(1).subscribe....` you are not returning the contents of subscribed data, but a Subscription variable which you can't access to get the data again

Comment: Ok, I see ... So I must assign it to this.books inside getBooks. Ok ...

Comment: So, this is related to another question of yours and you had said that you don't want to manipulate the Observable, does that still hold good? Because by your logic you are manipulating the data and trying to save for later use

Comment: ` return this.bookService.getByCategoryId(1).subscribe(...)` will return a subscription, not a custom type. You can assign the subscription to a variable for unsubscribe later, but you can't assign values in this way. See the answer below from Nguyễn Hoàng Phúc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to assign a Subscription into an array that is why you are getting these error:

I made this example using Observables and async pipe, I hope it helps you:

TS:

```
 /***
   *  books$ Observable is looking to any response
   *  of the method getByCategoryId. It is being displayed with async pipe in the view.
   */
  books$ = this.bookService.getByCategoryId(1);

  books: BookModel[];

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBooks();
  }

  /***
   *  Getbooks method does not return anything, 
   *  after the subscribe, a map is assigning the value to the books propertie
   *  which is in being render in the view without async pipe. 
   */
  getBooks(): void {
    this.bookService.getByCategoryId(1)
      .subscribe((payload: Payload<GetBooksResponse>) => {

        this.books = payload.result.map((response: GetBooksResponse) => {
          return <BookModel>{
            id: response.id,
            title: response.title
          };
        });

      });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let book of (books$ | async).result">
    {{ book | json }}
</div>

<br/>
<h3> Not Using | async </h3>

<div *ngFor="let book of books">
  {{ book | json }}
</div>
```

Try online at this link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9pzmw

If you ask me which approach is better, I would say it depends.

Async pipe with observable is my favorite to only show 'dumb data' in the view, but you should keep the subscription solution if you need this information in the component for anything else.

Comment: Why do you think he needs to unsubscribe ?

Comment: I am using books on the component view using ngFor. When will I need to unsubscribe in my component? I got confused on that ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura When you call a method that auto-complete the observable, you don't need to unsubscribe because the subscription ends when it is complete. if your `bookService.getByCategoryId` method makes calls `HttpClient.get`, then you do not need to unsubscribe. When your subscribtipn does not auto-complete, you need to manage your subscriptions.

Comment: There is other way to do, using angular pipe async and changing books to an observable, I will edit the answer to let you know both.

Comment: @ThomazCapra are you able to help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169715/mat-autocomplete-error-when-using-formarray)

Answer (score 4):

You need to return

```
getBooks(): Observable<BookModole[]> { ... }
```

then:

```
this.getBooks().subscribe(res => { this.books = res; });
```

Comment: are you able to help with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169715/mat-autocomplete-error-when-using-formarray)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to save a `Subscription` in a `typed Observable<T>` variable. Simply had to not subscribe since I use the `async` pipe in my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `of` to return new Observer from some type of collections

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of